# Ruby on Rails 5 - Passing data between two serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, active-model-serializers

I would like to know if it is possible to send data from a serializer to another, not from a controller to a serializer. Here is what I am doing :

```
class Serializer1 < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes \
    :id,
    :past_teachings

  def past_teachings
    p_teachings = Teaching.all
    p_teachings = ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(p_teachings,
                             each_serializer: Serializer2)
    #### I would like to send data to serializer2 from the current serializer ####
  end
end
```

I know it is possible to send data from a controller to a serializer. But it is possible to send data from a serializer to another?

Comment: What kind of data Omar? like some kind of options/parameters? Or serialized data? Or only collection as you are doing in example you've provided?

Comment: @lavilet : I would like to send an active record object id

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Using AMS 0.10.x, you could change your example in this way:

serializer_1.rb

```
class Serializer1 < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :past_teachings

  def past_teachings
    ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(PastTeaching.all, each_serializer: TeachingSerializer)
  end
end
```

teaching_serializer.rb:

```
class TeachingSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :name
end
```

If you want to access the current object being serialized, you can refer to 'object.' You can access the objects functions as object.function and its attributes as object['attribute'].

So, technically, you could do something like this (though in reality you would probably use AMS has_many relationship instead):

```
class Serializer1 < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :past_teachings

  def past_teachings
    ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(object.past_teachings.where(...), each_serializer: TeachingSerializer)
  end
end
```